# reliable way to delete older files in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to construct a reliable shell script to remove older files based on Xn of days using `find`. However, the script seems to work intermittently. Is there a better way? I list the files first to make sure I capture them, then use `-exec rm{}` to delete them.

I execute the script like so:
`/home/scripts/rmfiles.sh /u05/backup/export/test dmp 1`

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if [ $# != 3 ]; then
   echo "Usage: rmfiles.sh <directory> <log|dmp|par> <numberofdays>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

# Declare variables
HOURDATE=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`;
CLEANDIR=$1;
DELETELOG=/tmp/cleanup.log;

echo "Listing files to remove..." > $DELETELOG 2>&1
/usr/bin/find $CLEANDIR -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec ls -ltr {} \; > $DELETELOG 2>&1

echo "Removing files --> $HOURDATE" > $DELETELOG 2>&1
#/usr/bin/find $CLEANDIR -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec rm {} \; > $DELETELOG 2>&1
```

My sample directory clearly has files older than one day as of today, but `find` is not picking it up when it was before during some previous testing.

`Thu Sep 26 08:54:57 PDT 2013`

```
total 161313630
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba        10737418240 Sep 24 14:17 testexp01.dmp
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba        10737418240 Sep 24 14:20 testexp02.dmp
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba        10737418240 Sep 24 14:30 testexp03.dmp
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba            508 Sep 24 15:41 EXPORT-20130924.log
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba            509 Sep 25 06:00 EXPORT-20130925.log
-rw-------   1 oracle     dba            508 Sep 26 08:30 EXPORT-20130926.log
```

Comment: Please show us the parameters which you use to call the script. And are there spaces in the directory?

Comment: You can replace `-exec ls -ltr {} \;` with `-ls` or `-print`. That way, you don't have to run the find command twice.

Comment: Edited question to include my parameters passed. thanks.

Comment: @NooberGoober Are they nto shown on the logfile as well?

Comment: yes, tried with .log too and same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from a couple of small issues, the script looks good in general. My guess is that you want to add `-daystart` to the list of options so the base for the `-mtime` test is measured "from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours  ago. This option only affects tests which appear later on the command line."

If you have GNU find, then try `find -D tree,search,stat,rates` to see what is going on.

Some comments:

- Always quote variables to make sure odd spaces don't have an effect: `/usr/bin/find "$CLEANDIR" -name "*.$2" -mtime "+$3" ...`. Same with `CLEANDIR="$1"`
- Don't terminate lines with `;`, it's bad style.
- You can replace `-exec ls -ltr {} \;` with `-ls` or `-print`. That way, you don't have to run the find command twice.
- You should quote `{}` since some shells interpret them as special characters.

Comment: thanks for your input. I am looking deeper the the `man find` to evaluate other options. I don't see a `daystart` as an option. The OS is HP-UX.

Comment: HP-UX? You have my sympathy. In that case, you can probably only delete files older than 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

- `man find`
- `-mtime` mentions the read the comment at `-atime`
- *"When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional  part  is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago."* so this is also true for `-mtime`.